# Standard C header for ANSI VT100 escape sequences

Tags: c, header, escaping, vt100

Is there a standard C header containing ansi escape sequences for say vt100 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, this kind of hardware-specific stuff is not in the C standard.

Answer (score 4):

More a library than a header, but I think you are looking for [termcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termcap) or its modern replacement [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo).

Or perhaps the higher-level [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)). Or in this case, the drop-in replacement ncurses.

Comment: can you elaborate? I thought most systems switched over to the [terminfo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo)? Though, yes, (n)curses is the right way to access the terminal information DB.

Comment: @Dummy00001 Yes, it seems that terminfo should be mentioned.